# How to use NSObject to URLs with three20 properly

Tags: objective-c, iphone, three20

Basically i map my controllers to accept the address class to be passed into the listingpage controller. Which is done here:

```
[map from:@"tt://listingPage/(initWithResult:)" toViewController:[ListingPageController class]];
[map from:[Address class] name:@"result" toURL:@"tt://listingPage/(initWithResult:)"];
```

This url is being used in my table item which is being populated in the datasource:

```
for (Address *result in [(id<SearchResultsModel>)self.model results]) {
      NSString* url = [result URLValueWithName:@"result"];
      TTTableImageItem* tii = [TTTableMessageItem itemWithTitle:[result addressText] 
                                            caption:[result addressText]
                                            text:[result subText] 
                                            imageURL:[result image] 
                                            URL:url];
    [self.items addObject:tii];
}
```

My app crashes, I am not sure why, seems to be getting an invalidate view. any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What does your Address object look like? That could help.

Answer (score 0):

[Three20 URL Based Navigation Guide](http://three20.info/article/2010-10-06-URL-Based-Navigation#urlmapping)

```
[map from:[Address class] name:@"result" toURL:@"tt://listingPage/(initWithResult:)"];
```

The problem you have is that your code is attempting to call the method `(initWithResult:)` on the `[Address class]` instance.

What you need to do instead is to retrieve the `Result` parameter from the `Address` instance and use that to form your URL.

Example:

```
@interface ListingPageController : UIViewController
    - (id)initWithResult:(NSNumber *)resultId;
@end

@interface Address : NSObject
    @property (nonatomic, copy) NSNumber *resultId;
@end
```

So in this case you'd want to pass the `resultId` from `Address` to your `initWithResult:` call on `ListPageController`.

```
[map from:[Address class] name:@"result" toURL:@"tt://listingPage/(resultId)"];   
[map from:@"tt://listingPage/(initWithResult:)" toViewController:[ListingPageController class]];
```

Notice that there is **no colon** in `(resultId)`- since this a property getter method call.

Following the example:

```
Address *result = [[[Address alloc] init] autorelease];
result.resultId = [NSNumber numberWithInt:12345];
NSString* url = [result URLValueWithName:@"result"];
[[TTNavigator navigator] openURLAction:[TTURLAction actionWithURLPath:url]];
```

This would first convert `result` to the URL `tt://listingPage/12345` and then open that URL which would in turn call `ListingPageController initWithResult:12345`.